# CandleStick Chart:Replication of open and close displayed values while zooming

Tags: android, graph, androidplot, candlestick-chart

[image]Values are getting replicated in candlestick chart.

whenever I zoom chart the open and close values get cloned without `candlestickbar` i.e only values get displayed, stuck for many hours.

```
LineAndPointFormatter lpf = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.BLUE, Color.RED, null, null);
PointLabelFormatter pointLabelFormatterr=new PointLabelFormatter();
pointLabelFormatterr.getTextPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
lpf.setPointLabelFormatter(pointLabelFormatterr);
plot.addSeries(openVals, lpf);

LineAndPointFormatter lpf1 = new LineAndPointFormatter(null, null, null, null);
PointLabelFormatter pointLabelFormatterr1=new PointLabelFormatter();
pointLabelFormatterr1.getTextPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
pointLabelFormatterr1.vOffset=40;
lpf1.setPointLabelFormatter(pointLabelFormatterr1);
plot.addSeries(closeVals, lpf1);
```

Comment: How are you implementing the zoom behavior?

Comment: In the same way you did in demo app
Here is my demo which i have created for candlestick chart you can check it by following the given below link
https://github.com/DaminiBansal/CandleStick

Comment: Are you still having this issue?  I downloaded your code and ran it and could not replicate the problem.

Comment: On which device and OS you ran?Actually this issue replicated in the devices having OS below 6.So try to run it on lower devices

Comment: I was on a newer device running 6.  When I have a chance I'll try on an older device.  In the mean time, if it's an option for your project, you might try upgrading to Androidplot 1.1.0 as it now includes built in pan/zoom support for all instances of XYPlot.

Comment: After updating the library, problem still persist... .

Comment: Just to be certain - you've also removed your pan/zoom code and replaced it with PanZoom.attach(plot)?

Comment: Finally had a chance to try on a couple older devices but still could not replicate.